# Mining on HD6950 - Getting DAG error

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, dag, genoil

since I just upgraded my rig I got my old GPU laying around doing nothing, so I thought I might start to mine with it.

Its an XFX HD 6950 with 2GB of RAM.

Im running the following config:

- [Biostar A68N-2100](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=711#specification) (had that thing laying around)
- AMD Fusion APU E1-2100 Dual-Core Processor
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 7 64bit
- Virtual Memory set to 16 GB

Im getting DAG allocation errors though...

I tested the following graphics drivers;
- 14.1 beta
- 14.4
- 15.12

Using those variables in my .bat file:

```
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
```

geth is properly synced & I'm using ethminer-0.9.41-genoil-1.1.7.

**Can anyone help me with my issue?**

**EDIT: 
Would it be possible to run it in my main rig (RX 580) as a secondary card?**

(I know this rig (cpu & gpu) is not powerfull but I wanted to try it anyways and I could swap the mb & cpu out for a better one)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can mine with GPUs with less than 4 Gb of memory since the DAG increases with the blockchain size.

Comment: Would it be possible to run it in my main rig (RX 580) as a secondary card?